# Foreach loop display data in main

Tags: php, layout, foreach, yii2

I am working with a foreach loop and I want to make some banners in

> frontend/layouts/main

I created a model where I have these static functions:

```
public static function getUrl() {
    return Banner::find()->where(['Rel_User' => Yii::$app->user->identity->Id])->all();
}

public static function getImage() {
    return Yii::$app->basePath . '/web/' . $this->Image;
}
```

And I want to display this URL in my main:

```
<?php foreach (Banner::getUrl() as $key): ?>

    <div class="banner">
        <a href="<?= $key['Url'] ?>" title="">
            <img src="<?=Url::base(true)?>/img/banner.jpg" alt=""></a>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

The problem is that I have 3 banners assigned to the logged user and this loop displays only one banner. What did I do wrong? My second question is, what should I do to display only the URL from my database, because now the URL looks like:

```
http://my-page.frontend.localhost/www.google.com
```

but in my database it is:

```
url= www.google.com
```

Comment: For the question of the links not being external, you need to put http:// before <?= $key['Url'] ?>

Comment: Why you repeat 3 time the same code in foreach ? and why in the firts there is not div ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code has serious problem! You have this:

```
public static function getImage() {
    return Yii::$app->basePath . '/web/' . $this->Image;
}
```

It doesn't any sense of using `$this` keyword on a static function. When you made a function as `static`, you attach it on `class` not on `object` and `$this` pointer point to an `instance` of `class`.

For your problem, I suggest define a `has-many` relation on your `User` model as this:

```
public function getBanners()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Banner::className(), ['Rel_User' => 'id']);
}
```

and on your main view use something like this code:

```
<?php foreach (Yii::$app->user->identity->banners as $banner): ?>
    <div class="banner">
        <!-- Use your Banner model attributes from $banner variable -->
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```